# Abel's summation formula

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Originial Question:

Suppose $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converge, $b_k\nearrow \infty$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kb_k$ converge. Prove $\lim_{m\to\infty} b_m\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_m=0$

---

For this question, I have tried four different strategies. All of them are very pre-rigorous and seem almost hopeless.

My first strategy is to use the Squeeze Theorem. I was thinking that if $\{a_k\}$ are positive, I can deduce

\begin{equation}
0=\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k \leq \lim_{m\to\infty} b_m \sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k\leq \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kb_k=0
\end{equation}

But this strategy failed when I tried to generalize it by aiming to prove a weaker condition:
\begin{equation}
b_m\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k \in [\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k, \sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kb_k]\text{ or } [\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kb_k, \sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k]\text{ for large $m$}
\end{equation}
As $a_k=(-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{4^k}$ and $b_k=2^k$ serve for an counter example.

---

This led me to my second strategy. If I can not prove $\lim_{m\to\infty} b_m\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_n=0$ by squeezing it. Maybe I can prove this by showing
\begin{equation}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=m}^\infty (b_k-b_m)a_k=0
\end{equation}
But this seems only more complicated, and I fail to proceed.

---

My third strategy is to use the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem (sequence form of L'Hospital), namely

\begin{align}
  \lim_{m\to\infty}b_m\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\sum _{k=m}^\infty a_k}{\frac{1}{b_m}}&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k-\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k}{\frac{1}{b_{m+1}}-\frac{1}{b_m}}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{-a_mb_mb_{m+1}}{b_m-b_{m+1}}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}a_mb_m \frac{b_{m+1}}{b_{m+1}-b_{m}}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}a_mb_m(1+\frac{b_m}{b_{m+1}-b_m})
\end{align}

With this, we only wish to prove $\frac{b_{m}}{b_{m+1}-b_m}$ is bounded above, but again, I fail to proceed.

---

My last resort is to use the old-fashioned Abel's summation formula. I have deduced to
\begin{equation}
b_m\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k=\alpha b_m+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kb_k
\end{equation}
where $A_k=\sum_{n=1}^k a_n$ and $\alpha=\lim_{k\to\infty} A_k$.

For now, I can neither think of a way to proceed nor a possible tweak of the above argument. Appreciatie for any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Wlog assume $b_n >1$ since $b_n \to \infty$

Denote by $T_{m,M}=\sum_{m \le k \le M}a_kb_k \to 0$ with $m,M \to \infty$ by hypothesis.

Similarly let $S_{m,M}=\sum_{m \le k \le M}a_k\to 0$ with $m,M \to \infty$

Now let $A_{m,M}=\max_{m \le k \le M}|T_{k,M}| \to 0$ with $m,M \to \infty$

By partial summation we have

$S_{m,M}=T_{m,M}/b_m+(1/b_{m+1}-1/b_m)T_{m+1,M}+...+(1/b_M-1/b_{M-1})T_{M,M}$

So $$|S_{n,M}| \le A_{m,M}(|1/b_m|+|1/b_{m+1}-1/b_m|+...|1/b_M-1/b_{M-1}|)$$

But $1/b_n$ decreases to $0$ so expliciting the above we get

$$|S_{m,M}| \le A_{m,M}(2/b_m-1/b_M) \le \frac{2A_{m,M}}{b_m}$$

Fixing $\epsilon >0$ there is $m(\epsilon)$ st $A_{m,M} \le \epsilon, m, M \ge m(\epsilon)$ hence $$b_m|S_{m,M}| \le 2\epsilon$$ and letting $M \to \infty$ we have $b_m|S_{m,\infty}| \le 2\epsilon, m \ge m(\epsilon)$ since the convergence of $\sum a_k$ means that $S_{m,M} \to \sum_{k \ge m}a_k=S_{m,\infty}$

So $b_m S_{m,\infty}  \to 0$ as required!